# User input validation loop with try-with-resources loops endlessly after wrong user input

Tags: java, loops, validation, input, user-input

I am trying to create a user input validation loop and I would like to use a try-with-resources for the bufferedReader. However, when I insert the wrong input, **it starts looping endlessly printing the first message and the caught error message**.

**However, when I change the try-with-resources to a standard try catch block everything works as expected.**

I am assuming the **problem** is with the **try-with-resources block** but can't really understand why. Can anyone explain, please?

**Try with resources version**

```
        int nrOfVersions;
        int firstBadVersion;

        while (true) {
            try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)))
            {
                System.out.println("How many versions are there? ");
                nrOfVersions = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
                System.out.println("Which is the first bad version? ");
                firstBadVersion = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
                break;
            } catch (IOException | NumberFormatException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Retry, puto");
            }
        }
```

**Standard try-catch block**

```
        int nrOfVersions;
        int firstBadVersion;

        while (true) {
            try 
            {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                        
                System.out.println("How many versions are there? ");
                nrOfVersions = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
                System.out.println("Which is the first bad version? ");
                firstBadVersion = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
                
                bufferedReader.close();
                
                break;
            } catch (IOException | NumberFormatException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Retry, puto");
            }
        }
```

Comment: When the try with resources block is left, the opened resources are closed. Yours are readers based on `System.in`; when they are closed, they "close the underlying resource", ie `System.in`, so it can't be used after.

Comment: well, as it is intended, try-with-resource is closing the resource, including `System.in` - once closed, it will not be able to read from it (closing the `BufferedReader`, closes the `InputStreamReader`, which in turn closes `System.in`) and since `IOExcepition` is also being catch, it is not terminating the loop

Comment: @daniu I do understand that the resources are closed at the end of the try block but isn't the next logical step after the catch block is executed, to iterate a new version of the try-with-resources block therefore initializing a new reader and making it available for input?

Comment: @user16320675 - I do understand that the resources are closed at the end of the try block but isn't the next logical step after the catch block is executed, to iterate a new version of the try-with-resources block therefore initializing a new reader and making it available for input?